# In openpyxl, is there a way to apply a format without overwriting existing formats?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I've written a procedure that applies borders around a specified range. It works but is lengthy and clunky because when openpyxl applies a border it overwrites any existing borders. If not for that, I could structure it much more simply.

I would also like to write another procedure that applies a cel fill to a range, but when I tried this, it removes the borders created by this one. I also tried to include a cell format line in this code, but it is also overwritten by the borders (or overwrites them if you put it after the border 'border = Border' (... lines)

Also, whether this is possible or not, any suggestions on making this procedure more Pythonic are appreciated.

```
def range_border(ws, cell_range, bstyle="thin"):

    rows = ws[cell_range]

    numrows = len(rows)
    numcols = len(rows[0])

    # Borders on the corners
    if numrows == 1:
            if numcols == 1:

                    rows[0][0].border = Border(
                            left=Side(style=bstyle),
                            top=Side(style=bstyle),
                            bottom=Side(style=bstyle),
                            right=Side(style=bstyle),
                    )
            else:
                    rows[0][0].border = Border(
                            left=Side(style=bstyle),
                            top=Side(style=bstyle),
                            bottom=Side(style=bstyle),
                    )
                    rows[0][-1].border = Border(
                            right=Side(style=bstyle),
                            top=Side(style=bstyle),
                            bottom=Side(style=bstyle),
                    )
    else:
            if numcols == 1:

                    rows[0][0].border = Border(
                            left=Side(style=bstyle),
                            top=Side(style=bstyle),
                            right=Side(style=bstyle),
                    )
                    rows[-1][0].border = Border(
                            left=Side(style=bstyle),
                            bottom=Side(style=bstyle),
                            right=Side(style=bstyle),
                    )
            else:
                    rows[0][0].border = Border(left=Side(style=bstyle), top=Side(style=bstyle))
                    rows[0][-1].border = Border(
                            right=Side(style=bstyle), top=Side(style=bstyle)
                    )
                    rows[-1][0].border = Border(
                            left=Side(style=bstyle), bottom=Side(style=bstyle)
                    )
                    rows[-1][-1].border = Border(
                            right=Side(style=bstyle), bottom=Side(style=bstyle)
                    )

    # Borders on left and right
    if numrows > 2:
            for row in rows[1:-1]:
                    if numcols == 1:
                            row[0].border = Border(
                                    left=Side(style=bstyle), right=Side(style=bstyle)
                            )
                    else:
                            row[0].border = Border(left=Side(style=bstyle))
                            row[-1].border = Border(right=Side(style=bstyle))

    # # Border on top and botton
    if numcols > 2:
            if numrows == 1:
                    for col in rows[0][1:-1]:
                            col.border = Border(top=Side(style=bstyle), bottom=Side(style=bstyle))
            else:
                    for col in rows[0][1:-1]:
                            col.border = Border(top=Side(style=bstyle))
                    for col in rows[-1][1:-1]:
                            col.border = Border(bottom=Side(style=bstyle))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by overwrite but I suggest you create the borders outside of the processing which will make the code much easier to maintain. For applying borders to ranges of cells you might want to look at the source for how merged cells are handled.